# Swift NotificationCenter publisher subscriber called more than once?

Tags: swift, combine

So I am posting this notification:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .helloStack, object: obj)
```

**I am posting it only once**.

I have a model class that is subscribing to it like so:

```
helloSubscriber = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .helloStack)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] notification in

                // this is called more than once (twice)

                ....
            }
```

So, the closure, **is called more than once** and I checked to make sure that the notification is only posted once.

Why am I getting the closure called twice?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the sink

Answer (score 1):

In my case, calling `.removeDuplicates()` made the trick:

```
 NotificationCenter.default
         .publisher(for: .someName)
         .removeDuplicates()
         .compactMap { notification in
             notification.userInfo?["info"] as? String
         }
         .sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] (id, name) in
             self?.foo()
         })
         .store(in: &cancellables)
```

Try this code to avoid multiple sink calls

Comment: This might fail in case a notification is intentionally called twice

Answer (score 0):

I don't know wether the solution is correct or not but if 'obj' is a @State variable and there is a value change for @State variable it may execute the same line again i.e.,
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .helloStack, object: obj)

Comment: Thanks for the input. `obj` is not a @State variable. It's a struct that's passed in to the notification.